# Changing Email service address after turning on My Domain

Tags: lightning, email2case

My company's org have Email to Case enabled and our email service address is support@bunchofletters.naXX.case.salesforce.com. We are planning to move to Lightning and, of course, create my domain. But once we turn on My Domain and the URL is changed (so it's company.my.salesforce.com and not naXX.salesforce.com anymore), do we need to update email service address so it reflects the change? I checked and I can change email address, but email service address (I assume it's used for routing) is not editable.

This is pretty puzzling for me, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the email service addresses for email-to-case will not change. The org I work in now has My Domain, and a bunch of old email-to-case addresses that still work. (In fact, in checking, I realized that many of them have our old pod (na5) in them, even though we are now on a different one.)